# Prove that if $y>1$, then $\forall M\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists an $N$ in the natural numbers s.t. $n\geq N$ implies $y^n>M$.

Tags: inequality

For $y\in\mathbb{R}$, prove that if $y>1$, then $\forall M\in\mathbb{R}$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
n≥N \implies y^n>M.
$$

I'm not used to proving these kinds of questions so any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to prove this, and the preferred method will probably depend on your axioms and previously proven results. One way is as follows:

Consider $y=1+\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$. By the binomial theorem (the terms we are dropping are all positive), $y^n=(1+\epsilon)^n\geq 1+n\epsilon$. Setting $N=\frac{M}{\epsilon}$ then yields the result desired.

Comment: Just dropped by to say that inequality is known as Bernoulli's inequality. +1

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of seeing this is to note that $y^n$ is increasing (in $n$) and the differences $y^{n+1}-y^{n}=y^n(y-1)$ also increase, so it must go to infinity.